# Creating follow-up time variable

Tags: r

I've spent hours trying to find an answer to this but can't find a suitable code and I'm struggling with how to do this.

Below is an example of what my data looks like (named cohort) :

```
Diagnosis   Event      Death
1970-01-01  1975-01-01  1980-01-01
1970-02-02  NA          NA
1970-03-03  NA          1980-03-03
1970-04-04  1975-04-04  NA
1970-05-05  NA          NA
```

I want to create a follow-up time variable from the date of diagnosis to the event date, death date or 1990-01-01, whichever of these three things comes first.

i.e. so for the first piece of data the time to event would be 5 years, for the second it would be just under 20 years, for the third it would be 10 years, the 4th would be 5 years and the 5th row would be just under 20 years (the follow-up variable can be in number of days to the event and not years)

I'm under the assumption I need to use the difftime command but can't work out how to use it because I have multiple potential columns between which the time intervals are and I only want the time interval between the diagnosis column and the event which occurs earliest.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can list the second date options inside a `min()` call, and use that to calculate the follow up using difftime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin` to get minimum of Event date, death or `'1990-01-01'` and take the difference of it with `Diagnosis` date.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
        mutate(follow_up = pmin(Event, Death, na.rm = TRUE), 
               follow_up = if_else(is.na(follow_up), as.Date('1990-01-01'), follow_up),
               follow_up = as.integer(round(difftime(follow_up, Diagnosis, units = 'days')/365)))

df

#   Diagnosis      Event      Death follow_up
#1 1970-01-01 1975-01-01 1980-01-01         5
#2 1970-02-02       <NA>       <NA>        20
#3 1970-03-03       <NA> 1980-03-03        10
#4 1970-04-04 1975-04-04       <NA>         5
#5 1970-05-05       <NA>       <NA>        20
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised looking at my data that I have some deaths that occur after 1990-01-01. For these dates will it take the 1990-01-01 as the earliest date and not the date of death for the new variable follow-up?

Comment: Thanks, I realised later that the first answer you gave does use 1990-01-01 over the death date when 1990 occurs prior to the death
Thanks for giving an alternate solution